# Pair two 1D arrays by their value and index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D arrays of the same length as this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,  5])
b = np.array([7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 10])
```

The value of `a` is increasing while `b` is random.

I wanna pair them by their values following the steps below:

1. Pick the first unique value (`[1]`) of array `a` and get the unique numbers (`[7, 8]`) of array `b` at the same index.
   [image: step1]
2. If some paired numbers (`[8]`) appear again in `b`, then pick the number at the same index of `a`.
   [image: step2]
3. Then, some new paired number (`[2]`) which appears again in `a`, the numbers in `b` at the same index are selected.
   [image: step3]

Finally, the result should be:

```
[1, 2, 3] is paired with [7, 8, 9]

[4, 5] is paired with [10]
```

Comment: This is a nice whiteboard to explain your problem .. What have you attempted?

Comment: so, it seems like you have the logic all planned out. I suggest just implementing this using straightforward iteration and then speeding it up with `numba`

Comment: I wrote some code:```a_unique_value = np.unique(a)
for value in a_unique_value:
    a_index = np.argwhere(a==value)
    b_unique_value = np.unique(b[np.where(a==value)])```, but can't figure out how to accomplish it. The logic is clear, but I'm not sure of the code.

Comment: You might be able to iterate back and forward and append the results when your current loop is finished, remove all the data, then start back again with the next pair. Note that the time complexity may be O(n^2) or similar.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Thanks for the suggestion! I will update it when I finish the basic code tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no easy way for a vectorised (no looping) solution since it's a graph theory problem of finding connected components. If you still want to have a performant script that works fast on big data, you could use `igraph` library which is written in C.

### TL;DR

I assume your input corresponds to edges of some graph:

```
>>> np.transpose([a, b])
array([[ 1,  7],
       [ 1,  7],
       [ 1,  8],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 2,  9],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

So your vertices are:

```
>>> np.unique(np.transpose([a, b]))
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

And you would be quite happy (at least at the beginning) to recognise communities, like:

```
tags = np.transpose([a, b, communities])
>>> tags
    array([[ 1,  7,  0],
           [ 1,  7,  0],
           [ 1,  8,  0],
           [ 2,  8,  0],
           [ 2,  9,  0],
           [ 3,  8,  0],
           [ 4, 10,  1],
           [ 5, 10,  1]])
```

so that you have vertices `(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)` included in community number `0` and vertices `(4, 5, 10)` included in community number `1`.

Unfortunately, `igraph` doesn't support labeling graph nodes from 1 to 10 or any gaps of ids in labels. It must start from 0 and have no gaps in ids. So you need to store initial indices and after that relabel vertices so that edges are:

```
vertices_old, inv = np.unique(np.transpose([a,b]), return_inverse=True)
edges_new = inv.reshape(-1, 2)
>>> vertices_old
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10]) #new ones are: [0, 1, 2, ..., 8]
>>> edges_new
array([[0, 5],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 8],
       [4, 8]], dtype=int64)
```

The next step is to find communities using `igraph` (`pip install python-igraph`). You can run the following:

```
import igraph as ig
graph = ig.Graph(edges = edges_new)
communities = graph.clusters().membership #type: list
communities = np.array(communities)
>>> communities
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]) #tags of nodes [1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10]
```

And then retrieve tags of source vertices (as well as tags of target vertices):

```
>>> communities = communities[edges_new[:, 0]] #or [:, 1]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

After you find `communities`, the second part of solution appears to be a typical groupby problem. You can do it in `pandas:`

```
import pandas as pd
def get_part(source, communities):
    part_edges = np.transpose([source, communities])
    part_idx = pd.DataFrame(part_edges).groupby([1]).indices.values() #might contain duplicated source values
    part = [np.unique(source[idx]) for idx in part_idx]
    return part
>>> get_part(a, communities), get_part(b, communities)
([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])], [array([7, 8, 9]), array([10])])
```

### Final Code

```
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_part(source, communities):
    '''find set of nodes for each community'''
    part_edges = np.transpose([source, communities])
    part_idx = pd.DataFrame(part_edges).groupby([1]).indices.values() #might contain duplicated source values
    part = [np.unique(source[idx]) for idx in part_idx]
    return part

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,  5])
b = np.array([7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 10])

vertices_old, inv = np.unique(np.transpose([a,b]), return_inverse=True)
edges_new = inv.reshape(-1, 2)
graph = ig.Graph(edges = edges_new)
communities = np.array(graph.clusters().membership)
communities = communities[edges_new[:,0]] #or communities[edges_new[:,1]]
>>> get_part(a, communities), get_part(b, communities)
([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])], [array([7, 8, 9]), array([10])])
```

Comment: I compared this method with the looping one by using `a = np.random.randint(1000, size=10**7); b = np.random.randint(2000, size=10**7)`. The igraph method costs `11.2 s ± 433 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`, while the looping one costs `6.57 s ± 33.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. The looping is faster. Any idea?

Comment: It seems `np.unique()` is the main time-consuming process.

Comment: @XinZhan I'm working a lot to increase performance of `np.unique` these days. It seems to be quite slow in comparison with other methods like `np.bincount` or `numba/numexpr/cython` . You're using a lot of duplicated edges. Eliminating them really helps to speed up my code few times faster (2.5). But you need to find a faster way to remove duplicates. I'll come back with results after I'll test faster methods. You also test a very dense graph too which outputs one big component. Are you sure your data is dense?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, my data have many duplicated values. So don't worry, this won't affect my application. Good luck to your work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this by iterating both the arrays simultaneously and keeping track of what element is associated with which index of the result. Let me know if this works for you?

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,  5]
b = [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 10]

tracker_a = dict()
tracker_b = dict()

result = []
index = 0
for elem_a, elem_b in zip(a, b):
  if elem_a in tracker_a:
    result[tracker_a[elem_a]][1].add(elem_b)
    tracker_b[elem_b] = tracker_a[elem_a] 
  elif elem_b in tracker_b:
    result[tracker_b[elem_b]][0].add(elem_a)
    tracker_a[elem_a] = tracker_b[elem_b]
  else:
    tracker_a[elem_a] = index
    tracker_b[elem_b] = index
    result.append([{elem_a}, {elem_b}])
    index += 1
    
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[{1, 2, 3}, {8, 9, 7}], [{4, 5}, {10}]]
```

Complexity: O(n)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested it with another example: `a = np.append([1]*40, [2]*12) b = np.append(np.append([1]*20, [4]*20), [1]*12)`. The result is correct: `[[{1, 2}, {1, 4}]]`.

Comment: Just a friendly note, complexity is not the only thing that matters. Python loops waste a lot of time so it's also important to [vectorise](https://towardsdatascience.com/vectorization-in-python-46486819d3a) them in order to make your code performant on large datasets.